# Python - Find coefficients minimizing error in csv data

Tags: python, dataframe, scipy, coefficients

I've recently run into a problem. I have data looking like this :

| Value 1 | Value 2 | Target |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1345 | 4590 | 2.45 |
| 1278 | 3567 | 2.48 |
| 1378 | 4890 | 2.46 |
| 1589 | 4987 | 2.50 |
| ... | ... | ... |

The data goes on for a few thousand lines.

I need to find two values (A & B), that minimize the error when the data is inputted like so :

`Value 1 * A + Value 2 * B = Target`

I've looked into [scipy.optimize.curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html#scipy.optimize.curve_fit), but I can't seem to understand how it would work, because the function changes at every iteration of the data (since Value 1 and Value 2 are not the same over every row).

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunataly you have not provided any test data so I have come up with my own:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(V1,V2,A,B): #Target function
    return V1*A+V2*B

# Generate Test-Data
def generateData(A,B): 
    np.random.seed(0)
    V1=np.random.uniform(low=1000, high=1500, size=(100,))
    V2=np.random.uniform(low=3500, high=5000, size=(100,))
    Target=f(V1,V2,A,B) +np.random.normal(0,1,100)
    return V1,V2,Target
data=generateData(2,3) #Important: 
data={"Value 1":data[0], "Value 2":data[1], "Target":data[2]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data) #Similar structure as given in Table
```

`df.head()` looks like this:

```
    Value 1 Value 2 Target
0   1292.0525763109854  3662.162080896163   13570.276523473405
1   1155.0421489258965  4907.133274663096   17033.392287295104
2   1430.7172112685223  4844.422515098364   17395.412651006143
3   1396.0480757043242  4076.5845114488666  15022.720636830541
4   1346.2120476329646  3570.9567326419674  13406.565815022896
```

Your question is answered in the following:

```
## Plot Data to check whether linear function is useful 

df.head()
fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(211)
ax2=fig.add_subplot(212)
ax1.scatter(df["Value 1"], df["Target"])
ax2.scatter(df["Value 2"], df["Target"])



def fmin(x, df): #Returns Error at given parameters
    def RMSE(y,y_target): #Definition for error term 
        return np.sqrt(np.mean((y-y_target)**2))
    A,B=x
    V1,V2,y_target=df["Value 1"], df["Value 2"], df["Target"]
    y=f(V1,V2,A,B) #Calculate target value with given parameter set
    return RMSE(y,y_target)

res=minimize(fmin,x0=[1,1],args=df, options={"disp":True})
print(res.x)
```

I prefere `scipy.optimize.minimize()` over `curve_fit` since you can define the error function yourself. The documentation can be found [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html).
You need:

- a function `fun` that returns the error for a given set of parameter `x` (here `fmin` with RMSE)
- an initial guess `x0` (here `[1,1]`), if your guess is totally off you will probably do not find a solution or (with more complex problems) just a local one
- additional arguments `args` provided to the `fun` here the data `df` but also helpful for fixed parameters
- `options={"disp":True}` is for printing additional information
- your parameters can be found besides further information in the returned variable `res`

For this case the result is:

```
[1.9987209 3.0004212]
```

Similar to the given parameters when generating the data.

Answer (score 2):

The function `curve_fit` takes 3 arguments :

- a function `f` that takes an *input*  argument, let's call it `X` and parameters `params` (as many as you want)
- the *input* `X_data` you have from your dataset
- the *output* `Y_data` you have from your dataset

The point of this function is the give you best `params` to input in `f(X_data, params)` to get `Y_data`.

Intuitively the form `X` in your function `f` is a simple numpy 1D array, but actually it can have the form you want. Here your input a tuple of two 1D arrays (or a 2D array if you want to implemente it this way).

Here's a code example :

```
import numpy as np 
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

X_data = (np.array([1345,1278,1378,1589]),
          np.array([4590,3567,4890,4987]))
Y_data = np.array([2.45,2.48,2.46,2.50])

def my_func(X, A, B):
    x1, x2 = X
    return A*x1 + B*x2

(A, B), _ = curve_fit(my_func, X_data, Y_data)

interpolated_results = my_func(X_data, A, B)
relative_error_in_percent = abs((Y_data - interpolated_results)/Y_data)*100
print(relative_error_in_percent)
```